# pandas dataframe from dict preserves string indices (which mis-orders)

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading data from a json file which, via json.load, returns a dict such as this:

```
a = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '10': 10, '2': 2, '3': 3 ... etc.}
```

When I turn this into a pandas dataframe (`b = pd.DataFrame(a)`), the DataFrame preserves indices with strings:

```
print b.index
Index([u'0', u'1', u'10', u'11', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', 
u'9'], dtype='object')
```

Is there a straightforward/pythonic way to sort this into 0:12 order? I feel like this should be trivial but my attempts with sort_index haven't worked (yet?)

Comment: Do you mean `b = pd.Series(a)`?

Comment: Also do you want the index to have string elements? Or ints?

Comment: Perhaps my example is too stripped down. My json file (at some point, previously, created by `pd.json.dumps()`) in this case has 6 columns and 31 indices. I want to get one of the columns of data, but sorted by the indices as if they were ints: 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: If you convert the index to `int` and sort then this is straightforward. You can convert back if you desire strings.

Comment: Feel free to upvote your selected answer in addition to accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post a more complete example?

With what you have, the following works for me:

```
a = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '10': 10, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4}
b = pd.Series(a).to_frame()
b.index = map(int, b.index)  # or pd.to_numeric(b.index)
b.sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed...the combinaion of map(int, b.index) *and* b.sort_index().

Comment: If you are going to create the series first then use s.index.astype(int).  Otherwise use pd.Series(dict(zip(map(int, a.keys()), a.values())))

Comment: Contrary to my example, I'm looking at a DataFrame, not just a series. What's the equivalent to your second approach, @piRSquared, with a 2D dataset?

Comment: @Nick you should post a minimal example that represents your data.